# Does IDEA support Tapestry 4?

Tags: intellij-idea, tapestry

Does IntelliJ IDEA support Tapestry 4? I've got a Tapestry 4.1.x code base to work with, and as far as I can tell the Tapestry facet (at least in 10.5) only supports Tapestry 5, which as I understand it is completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Tapestry 4 support in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

The HandyTapestry plugin ( http://handyedit.com/handytapestry.html ) had pretty good support for T4 - i'm not sure however if it's compatible with the latest IDEA version.

Comment: Interesting. Since the last version mentioned is IDEA 6, I suspect not, but thanks for the link.